# Which Chef resource can I execute multiple lines of BASH code using Chef's sensititve property?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I would like to prevent any output to the chef client when running BASH code with templates, and recipes that may contain variables with sensitive data.

In my case, I'm automating a created MySQL user, which takes a variable from the encrypted data bag, as well as manually securing/hardening the MySQL install (via command line). When I run the chef-client, it shows the variable output to the user, including the MySQL password.

'execute' allows the sensitive property, but this issue involves a bash script that uses the variable(s) multiple times, not just a one-liner. I could do it using a continuation of ampersands '&&', but that would look messy the longer the script gets.

'script' and 'bash' do not allow 'sensitive' to be used as a property, and returns an 'uninitialized constant' error. This kind of sucks, since it would be such a great feature here.

Thoughts on how to keep script variables hidden from chef-client output?

```
dbag = data_bag_item('pass', 'mysql')
db_pass = dbag["mysqlpass"]

bash 'install_mysql' do
  sensitive True
  code <<-EOC
    systemctl start mysqld.service && systemctl enable mysqld.service
    mysqladmin -u root password #{db_pass}
    # automate secure mysql install
    mysql -u root -p#{db_pass} -e "UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('#{db_pass}') WHERE User='root'"
    mysql -u root -p#{db_pass} -e "DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE User='root' AND Host NOT IN ('localhost', '127.0.0.1', '::1')"
    mysql -u root -p#{db_pass} -e "DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE User=''"
    mysql -u root -p#{db_pass} -e "DELETE FROM mysql.db WHERE Db='test' OR Db='test\_%'"
    mysql -u root -p#{db_pass} -e "FLUSH PRIVILEGES"
    # create mysql user, and pass
    mysql -e "CREATE DATABASE mysqldb;" -u root -p#{db_pass}
    mysql -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mysqldb.* TO "mysqluser"@"localhost" IDENTIFIED BY '#{db_pass}';" -u root -p#{db_pass}
    mysql -e 'FLUSH PRIVILEGES;' -u root -p#{db_pass}
  EOC
end
```

I've also tried:

```
script 'install_mysql' do
  sensitive True
  ...
end
```

and

```
cookbook_file '/tmp/install_mysql.sh'
  source install_mysql.sh
  ...
end

execute 'install_mysql' do
  sensitive True
  command "/tmp/install_mysql.sh"
end
```

Comment: My only thought right now is to place a bash script in cookbook_file, than execute it with the sensitive property. Are there other ways to do it within the same recipe?

Comment: It appears that won't even work as it also brings up an 'uninitialized constant' error in the chef-client.

Comment: This would be a bug, every Chef resource supports the sensitive property.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing, since the execute was failing as well. I'm currently running chef_ver 13.8.5. I might have to submit a bug request if it truly is.

Comment: Please include both your code (minus secrets) and the full error text in your question. You can edit them in using the link under the question.

Comment: @coderanger updated.

Comment: BTW, I'd tend to suggest putting your sensitive data in the environment, not in the code. Putting a password on the command line exposes it to other processes running on the machine at the same time (`mysql` could potentially rewrite its command line after it started to obscure the password, but there's still a window before that rewrite happens), so it's dangerous even if Chef itself doesn't log it.

Comment: Note the warnings in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/password-security-user.html; its warning about environment variables' security is inapplicable on modern Linux, but otherwise the guidance is generally accurate.

Comment: That should be `sensitive true`. Ruby spells booleans in lower case.

Comment: But also yes, `sensitive` mode is not a magic bullet and you would best combine it with environment variables or temp files for credentials :)

Comment: @coderanger one of those 'good grief' moments, thanks for clarifying. https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html shows 'sensitive Ruby Types: True, False'. I was also not aware that Ruby used lower case boolean, much appreciated.

Comment: Classes in Ruby are consts so the types are `TrueClass` and `FalseClass` :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy and CodeRanger: Roger, will do. Thank you for bringing this to my attention, I will make the appropriate env var changes to increase added security.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I've never read that 'End-User Guidelines for Password Security' document before, thanks for sharing. I was unaware of .mylogin.cnf, which should work out great for creating users. However, the hardening of MySQL requires either using the mysql_secure_installation script which requires manual intervention, or the manual method described above. My aim to to keep it fully automated.

Comment: `mysql_secure_installation` *can* be used unattended. Note the `--use-default` and `--defaults-file`/`--defaults-extra-file` options, intended specifically for that case. (That said, I'm an old-timer who still considers the MySQL team utterly untrustworthy for a serious database product after their late-1990s efforts to discourage use of relational integrity, transactional integrity, stored procedures, or any other feature they didn't support at the time as cruft without benefit sufficient to justify the performance cost for typical non-bank use cases).

Comment: --use-default*, this is awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered in comments, `true` and `false` are lowercase in Ruby. Using `True` makes Ruby try to look for a const that doesn't exist.